# How can I respond a json file with status code when meet server error?

Tags: python, api, flask

I'm building a flask api. Instead of respond default html file, I want to respond a json file when my api meet an unexpected server error, the json file looks like this:

```
{"code":"0007"}
```

Does anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

For sending JSON response on server error you can use Flask-JSON module, it will serve your purpose.
[Flask-JSON](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-JSON/)